# Matplotlib Scatter plot filter color (Colorbar)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have some data let say `x`, `y`, and `z`. All are `1D` arrays. I have done a scatter plot with `z` as color as;

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.scatter(x,y,c=z,alpha = 0.2)
 plt.xlabel("X")
 plt.ylabel("Y")
 plt.ylim((1.2,1.5))
 plt.colorbar()
```

The `z` values are normalized and its between `-1` to `1`. I have attached the figure below.

The question I have is; How can I filter the colors such that let say the points that have a color value between `-0.25` to `0.25` disappear form the figure (i.e set the color to white).

[image]

The values for `x`, `y`, and `z` can be provided if needed to answer this question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: masked arrays could be a nice option: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Plotting_values_with_masked_arrays

Comment: You can make a custom colorbar, or use one that already has pale values around 0 (`summer`, maybe?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

# prepare random data
stats = -1, 1, 200
x = np.random.uniform(*stats)
y = np.random.uniform(*stats)
z = np.random.uniform(*stats)

# mask unwanted data
thresh = 0.4
mask = np.abs(z) <= thresh
x_ma = np.ma.masked_where(mask, x)
y_ma = np.ma.masked_where(mask, y)
z_ma = np.ma.masked_where(mask, z)
```

And do the plotting:

```
fig, (ax_left, ax_right) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 4),
                                        sharex=True, sharey=True)
img_left = ax_left.scatter(x, y, c=z)
fig.colorbar(img_left, ax=ax_left)
img_right = ax_right.scatter(x_ma, y_ma, c=z_ma)
fig.colorbar(img_right, ax=ax_right)
```

gives following result:

[image: plot]

The plot on the right side hides all points that fall below the chosen threshold.

Comment: Depending on what the masked values mean, this bothers me, as the colorbar seems to imply that there *could* be values in [-0.4, 0.4] but *aren't*.  I'd edit the colormap so that the colorbar is also white in that range. (Or maybe the masked values really are non-data.)